# $SL(2)/U(2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let  $G= SL(2)$ and $H=U(2)$ the set of $2x2$ matrices of type $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & * \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. By Chevalley Theorem $G/H$ can be immersed in $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{C}^2 \oplus \mathbb{C})$ and can be described as the set of $g \cdot (\mathbb{C}e_1 \oplus \mathbb{C})$ with $g \in G$. Why is $G/H$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\}$? They are both quasiprojective varieties, so I should find an open covering of affine sets $U_i \subset SL(2)$ such that if $\phi : G/H \to \mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\}$, $\phi|_{U_i}$ is an isomorphism of affine varieties (therefore regular and invertible). Any hints?

Comment: Because $G$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ and $H$ is the stabilizer of the point $(1,0)$.

Comment: I am a beginner at this: could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Sasha probably won't be more specific I'll add some more details to the answer. Although the content is virtually the same the wording might be a bit more psychologically comforting.

There is a natural action of $G = \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ on $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{0\}$.

**Exercise.** This action of $G$ on $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ is transitive, meaning that, if you pick two points $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{0\}$, you can always find a $g \in G$ such that $gx = y$.

Now consider the point $x = (1, 0)$. By the orbit--stabilizer theorem, there should be an isomorphism between $G / G_x$ (the quotient of $G$ by the stabilizer at $x$) and $Gx$ (the orbit of $x$).

**Exercise.** In case you've only seen the orbit--stabilizer theorem for discrete groups, prove that it also works in the expected way for Lie groups acting on topological spaces.

**Exercise.** Prove that the stabilizer of the point $x = (1, 0)$ is isomorphic to $H$. Also prove that the orbit $Gx$ is all of $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{0\}$. Conclude the desired result.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. I tried to prove that $G_x$ is $H$, but I found that a matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ does not need to have $d =1$ in order to stabilise $x$. In particular, I found that $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix}$ also stabilises $x$. What am I missing? Next, to prove that $Gx$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2  \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\}$ do I have to find a biregular application between those affine varieties?

Comment: I was a bit thrown off guard by the first point too, but I think what you can notice is that $d$ must be nonzero, so that you can always 'normalise' the second column so that you replace $(b\,d)$ by $(b/d\, 1)$. This should specify an isomorphism between the stabilizer and $H$. To prove $Gx$ is $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{0\}$, this should be  immediate from the definitions once you've verified that the $G$-action is transitive!

Comment: Also, eventually I figured $G= SL(2)$ in this case, so that’s why $d =1$, I just edited.